# Php get the timestamp values grouped by months

Tags: php

Suppose that i have

```
$time1 = 1492894800 //23/04/2017
$time2 = 1503521999  //23/08/2017
```

I would like to get timestamps grouped by months such that

```
get timestamp with rangess between months preserving first and last month of $time1 and $time2 such that i should have

 1 23/04/2017 to 30/04/2017
 2 01/05/2017 - 31/05/2017
 ....... //continue full months and lastly

 01/08/2017 - 23/08/2017
```

i have tried

```
$timearrays = $this->getMontTimestampRanges($time1, $time2); 

public function getMontTimestampRanges($ts1, $ts2){

    $start    = (new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $ts1)));
    $end      = (new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $ts2)));

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    $timestamps = [];
    foreach ($period as $dt) {
      //am stuck here on how to group based on the months      

      ..push to array
    }

    return $timestamps;

}
```

so the final array i would like it to be of the form:

```
$timestamps = [
    0=>["from":, "to":  ] //first month(april)
    1=>[ ] //second month may 
 ]
```

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code

Try this:

```
<?php
$time1 = 1492894800 ;//23/04/2017
$time2 = 1503521999;  //23/08/2017
$timearrays = getMontTimestampRanges($time1, $time2); 
var_dump( $timearrays);
 function getMontTimestampRanges($ts1, $ts2){

    $start    = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $ts1));
    $end      = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $ts2));

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    $timestamps = [];

    $startM = $period->getStartDate()->format('m');
    $endM  = $period->getEndDate()->format('m');

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
      //am stuck here on how to group based on the months      
        //start
        if($startM == $dt->format('m'))
        {
           $timestamps[] = array('start'=>$start->format('Y-m-d'),'end'=>$dt->format('Y-m-t'));
        }
        elseif($endM == $dt->format('m'))
        {
            $timestamps[] = array('start'=>$dt->format('Y-m').'-01','end'=>$end->format('Y-m-d') );
        }
        else
        {
            $timestamps[] = array('start'=>$dt->format('Y-m').'-01','end'=>$dt->format('Y-m-t'));
        }


    }

    return $timestamps;

}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8527e45427fd0114f1e058fffc1885e460807a0a

Hope it helps.

Comment: this fails when dates are close eg: 31st may and 1st june period array is only one value, and also when you the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

After clarifying your query on my last answer,  I have decided to delete my answer and post a new answer.

```
$start = 1492894800; //23/04/2017
$end = 1503521999;  //23/08/2017

$steps = date('Ym', $end) - date('Ym', $start);

$timestamps = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= $steps; $i++) {
    $base = strtotime("+{$i} months", $start);

    $timestamps[] = array(
        'from' => $i == 0 ? date('Y-m-d', $start) : date('Y-m-01', $base),
        'to' => $i == $steps ? date('Y-m-d', $end) : date('Y-m-t', $base)
    );

//  If we want timestamps   
//  $timestamps[] = array(
//      'from' => strtotime(date('Y-m-01', $base)),
//      'to' => strtotime(date('Y-m-t', $base))
//  );
}

print_r($timestamps);
```

[Ideone link](https://ideone.com/D6Xcng)